# Using a for-loop to get the result of a .reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm new to Javascript and I've been trying to solve this tutorial exercise. I'm trying to add array elements using a for-loop. I pseudo-solved it using a .reduce() method but I'm still pondering over how I could do it with a for-loop (This is what is actually asked)

I have an array a = ['ant', 'bat','cat',42] and using a for-loop I have to add all elements. A let/var named "total" has to be set so that it equals the total plus the current element. I coudn't figure that one out... Instead I google-searched and discovered the method .reduce() which works. But I'd really like to solve this problem...

> total = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
>   [Function: total]
>
> console.log(a.reduce(total));
>   antbatcat42

Normally I should have something looking like this :

> let total = ".?.?."
>
> for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
>   ... console.log(total.?.?.)
>   ... }

Comment: Seems to be a bad tutorial if it does not explain assignment `=` and concatenation `+` before ....

Comment: Well, They talked about that but I didn't know that I could use such operator as "+="...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a variable with empty string and keeping [adding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators) the values to it as you're looping through the array.

```js
let a = ['ant', 'bat','cat',42]

let total= ''

for( let i=0;i< a.length; i++){
  total += a[i];
}

console.log(total)
```

Here you're just concatenating all the values so it's a good case to use [Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```js
let a = ['ant', 'bat','cat',42]

console.log(a.join(''));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was just missing the "+=" operator. Yes the next question asks us if there is a difference between total and a.join("") to make us realize that.